# Software development methodology difference

Tags: agile, methodology, jad

Does anyone happen to know if Joint Application Development is categorized under Agile methodology or are they two separate development processes? It appears that SCRUM is a type of agile but JAD is related to RAD and is outside of agile.

Any information on differences are appreciated.

Comment: What does it matter?  Are you resolving a bet?  Are you forbidden from using Agile methods?  Why split this hair?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agile is not a methodology in itself.  It is a set of guidelines ([the manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/)), a mindset,  a way of approaching software development.  SCRUM is one manifestation of that as a concrete methodology.

JAD (it appears from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_application_design)) is related to requirements gathering in DSDM.  DSDM is typically classed as an [agile methodology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) so I guess your answer is there.

Comment: JAD (like many parts of Agile) is a technique that can be applied or not applied.  TDD, continuous integration, etc., are all techniques that are optional.